# PCl No such file or directory

Tags: c++, header-files, libraries, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

When I try to build a file that involves PCL, I get this error next to each line where I try to include a PCL file. I have tried moving the files into the same directory, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visualization tutorial is outdated, so if you get this error, look at the actual documentation for help.